# How to install Ktorrent 4.1.1?

Tags: 11.04, ktorrent

Already tried adding the Kubuntu PPA (Which tipically worked for past ktorrent versions (I always use Ktorrent because of several advantages) and it still appears like 4.0.5 in the repositories. What can i do to install the latest version?

NOTE - Also tried this PPA https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ktorrent/+packages but i recommend not to use it since it gave me some crazy problems, like instead of upgrading ktorrent it deleted it and then did not let me install it.

Comment: Why would you break something that isn't broken (yet)? The current version is stable and works well. An awful answer would be: compile it yourself. But that requires a lot development files.

Comment: Actually 4.0.5 does not work well. I have had about 5 crashes over the past 3 days. Already send the crashlog to the kde devs. THIS is the main reason why i want to update. Also as i mention in the Question i tested that PPA and breaks stuff and BECAUSE of that i learned not use it and posted here for anybody else that wanted to use it to beware.

Comment: You can compile it yourself, described here:[faq](http://ktorrent.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ).Alternatively why not to install Kubuntu as a session and install it through a ppa which is more better and safer form both version stable and unstable?

Comment: Installing Kubuntu will also give the 4.0.5 version of Ktorrent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)Install kde desktop as a session; in synaptic** `kde-standard` :
[image]

**2)Then in Konsole; kde terminal**:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/natty
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

[Source](http://mygeekopinions.blogspot.com/2011/05/ktorrent-411-is-released-how-to-install.html)

Note:This will not install ktorrent yet.

**3)Go back to Ubuntu; install ktorrent from the software center or click [here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ktorrent).**

**4)Don't open the program in ubuntu.First switch to the kde session and open it.**

**5)Then return to ubuntu and now you have Ktorrent 4.1.1 in Ubuntu!! :D**

[image]

Comment: Note: This worked for me very well.and I am now downloading using it.And you can try it keeping in mind any possible error. So good luck! and I hope this help!:)

Answer (score 0):

However, @Lekensteyn, he wants a different version for whatever reasons, you may have to compile it yourself to get the version you want.

If the update method as shown above doesn't work, then you could try `sudo apt-get remove Ktorrent` in the terminal.