# Installing μTorrent

Tags: installation, tar

Hello i'm trying to install uTorrent to my Ubuntu 11.04

I'm downloading it from [here](http://www.utorrent.com/intl/tr/downloads/complete?os=linux) . But it's a **.tar.gz** file. I'm untaring it with

```
tar -xzvf utorrent-server-3.0-25053.tar.gz
```

command. But there isn't any **make** file, etc. I can understood, how can i install it ?

Comment: The file you downloaded is a server version of uTorrent and does not look like it's the client. Are you sure you need this one?

Comment: No actually i couldn't find client. i need client.

Comment: @Rinzwind I guess this is a default version. It does not GUI support. Instead it relies on web server component. So you access utorrent functionality via web browser using localhost and particular port.

Comment: You can download the Windows uTorrent client and run it in Wine.  It works 100% effectively under Wine.

Comment: Are you aware that Ubuntu comes with a bit torrent client installed by default? You can just open torrent files. You don't need to install anything. Just in case you didn't know. :)

Comment: There is also rtorrent.. which is way better than utorrent.

Comment: related question -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/48546/list-of-gui-based-bittorrent-clients

Comment: @user606723: rTorrent is lacking many modern client features.  This is without regard to interface, just client capabilities.  I've been really happy with transmission-cli, it's both modern and lightweight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a tar file with all the files already in it (I had a peek inside the tar file).

The command to start it looks like `utserver` inside `./utorrent-server-v3_0`

`utserver: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, not stripped`

Also have a look at `./utorrent-server-v3_0/docs/` for the file `uTorrent_Server.html`.

If you are looking for the client you need `wine` to run it. I would advice looking for another client. Both deluge and transmission are perfect for downloading torrents.

Answer (score 1):

Utorrent is providing 32bit executable directly. So if you have 32bit Ubuntu installation then follow these steps.

1. Go to extracted folder
2. run utserver

   ./utserver
3. Now go to browser and type http://localhost:8080

You might need to configure few things. However, as the binary is 32bit, I could not run this lib on my 64bit OS setup.

[Follow this official discussion page for more detailed installation steps.](http://forum.utorrent.com/viewtopic.php?id=83842)

Comment: Did you install the 32bit libraries, `ia32-libs`?  You can install that on 64bit and run 32bit binaries

Comment: @The Evil Phoenix No I do not have these libs. I didn't know that you require these libs. I was under impression that 32bit libraries can run on 6bit OS as they 64bit OS have backward compatibility.
I guess backward compatibility is provided via these special libs.

Comment: Those libs are installed automatically in a 32bit system.  In Windows, libs for 32bit and 64bit are installed with 64bit versions.  In Linux, 64bit only installs 64bit libs, but installing `ia32-libs` gets you the 32bit libs (which are installed with teh 32bit version of Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

If you like utorrent in Windows and want the same experience in Ubuntu you better give up utorrent here (at least at its present stage). I also tried utorrent in Wine and it was unstable and heavy. 
The most utorrent-like experience in Ubuntu is through **qBittorrent** and **Flush**. See [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/a/111087).