# Transmission not downloading

Tags: 11.10, transmission

I'm using the Transmission which was shipped in 11.10.
All the configurations in Ubuntu 11.10 are the same as they are in my Mac OS.

In Ubuntu, Transmission is not downloading at all: 0 peers at all times.

When booting into Mac OS, all seeds turned out to be fine (high speeds, lots of seeders).

Comment: Me too, randomly, but if I leave it for some time, it catches the train. So if you weren't patient, try it, and if not I don't know what is the issue. Some suggest changing Encryption in privacy options, especially if it's set on 'require encryption' and tweaking Privacy tab in general. I don't have references right now, but quick Google can lead to those I guess

Comment: Running "sudo ufw allow out 6969/tcp" may fix problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Transmission menu go to `Edit` → `Preferences` → `Network`.

Check if your port (usually *51414* by default) is open, if not go forward by units (51415,51416..) until you find an opened one, this should work.

Be sure to disable your firewall for transmission (if you have set one).

Comment: I'd add to it that maybe you should enable the Network->UPnP option.

Answer (score 0):

As I previously recommended Ktorrent I feel I should report on that.

Lately I was not satisfied with Ktorrent anymore (although I would prefer it to Transmission any day) because it seemed still rather heavy and even speed seemed too low (or maybe other settings need adjusting ? - I only adjusted the upload speed and nothing else).

So, I tried **qBittorrent** and I recommend it, for the speed and also because it is lighter than Ktorrent. (Or at least gives that impression. Looking at the task manager, they are not very different, but I find qBittorrent more responsive and better adjusted - it looks like utorrent - while Ktorrent, while being a decent program has odd features like that you cannot close the program from the taskbar icon, it has tabs that seem useless and that you cannot close - well, in fact there's a close button to the right, it took me one month to see it, and so on.)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hydr0g3n/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

Then, I tried **Flush**, which is lighter, while still having a lot of features and looking basically the same. It surely deserves a try.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:konishchevdmitry/flush
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flush
```

When having issues with a torrent client it is advisable to use multiple ones to test them.

Considering the clients with more features and settings, **Deluge** is one of the most used, reliable and with a lot of support (I mean wiki, faqs etc).
Another one that is very interesting is **Tixati** ([here](http://www.tixati.com/download/linux.html)).  It has A LOT  of features for advanced users. (Don't worry, colors are customizable too :-))

Comment: I would say that this doesn't directly address the user's problem, since 1. If there are problems with routing or the firewal the problem is likely to also apply to other torrent applications, 2. Transmission is OK, since it has a non-bloated interface, full-fledged feature set and a large user base. 3. The user's question addresses Transmission.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some possible answers for your question:

From the transmission forums : https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=7326
From ubuntuforums : http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-819812.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

You can also instal Deluge Bit torrent client. I think it is in the software centrum.  You can also find it here: 
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=deluge&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all
Deluge is very similar with Utorrent.  If this is not working too for you there must be an onthe reason why.

Answer (score -1):

I have this problem sometimes too, it usually has to do with the port being used. I suggest going to edit -> preferences -> network and selecting chose a random port when opened. Then just restart it.