# uTorrent 3.1.2 via Wine -> Black background of main panel

Tags: wine, bittorrent

As uTorrent for Linux is horrible, I use Windows versions via Wine. But when I start it I get a windows like on the image

[image]

Anyone knows how to remove this black background from the main panel?

Comment: Goto wine configuration and try diffrent msstyle


you may can change colur scheme manually too

Comment: @AboobackerMk Can you be more specific? I cannot find that. I open `Wine configurations` and then go where? I tried libraries tab but I cannot find `msstyle`.

Comment: Oh sorry you have to download msstyle(windows theme file from internet)

and chose it as new system theme

Comment: Oh, I'll try this then

Comment: Have you considered using a [different torrent client](http://askubuntu.com/q/48546/6969)?

Comment: @Lekensteyn No. I like this one and I've been using it for 10 years.

Comment: @ubuntico  - what version of wine are you using?  Have you tried the wine 1.4rc's?

Comment: @Lekensteyn Actually Deluge looks nice. I will try it as well.

Comment: @fossfreedom 1.3.28. I may try that as well although I do not like installing non-final Wine due to bad experience in the past

Comment: Try [qBittorrent](http://www.qbittorrent.org/). It's almost the same as uTorrent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto wine configuration and try diffrent msstyle

now mine is look like this

install win7 msstyle theme

[image]

if it wont work goto preferances - ui settings -alternate wall paper

Comment: I'm having the same problem as ubuntico. I've upgraded wine to 1.4 and have tried changing the msstyle however the background is still black. Maybe only some msstyles work? I wasn't able to find how to change the wallpaper, there's no "UI Setting" anywhere I can find.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround as stated by ax 34noff:
workaround i use: Preferences/Advanced/sys.enable_wine_hacks = false torrents list works good ...but free area of it remains black.

Answer (score 0):

you use virtualbox and install on it microsoft windows like xp and the use it only for software that run in windows only

i see this the best solution for program because wine is very best but will take alot of time to solve any problem with it

so try virtualbox and this site https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Come on man :). I use vbox for ages and there's no way I would install another virtual OS just to use uTorrent. The previous versions worked well via Wine and this is the first one I am having problems. You should trust Wine more ;).

Comment: no i trust and like wine very much it's not only software and huge project in my opinion and i like it but like you know wine need experience to solve problem and any beginner like me will take more time to solve any problem so i see virtualbox is good way to that and i didn't face any problem with it but wine as i said is very high it can run games like gta and assassin creed and other this games need more dll , ocx files to run so i like it but vbox is fast solution i think "Aboobacker Mk" reach to solution

Answer (score 0):

Go to preferences/Advanced and set sys.enable_wine_hacks to false

Be sure that you are running it with win7, the background of the program remains black but now you can click on the torrents.

Checked with: Ubuntu 12.04, Wine 1.4 and Utorrent 3.2.2