# Transmission causes internet to stop working

Tags: 12.10, internet, transmission

I’m getting the same problem has anyone fixed this. Running ubuntu 12.10 and same thing as above. Start computer internet works fine. start bittorent client then connection goes south after 5 to 10 minutes. I have a netgear n300. was running windows with it no problem. windows got a virus no surprise there. so I changed over to Ubuntu 12.10. Got the N300 to work, got the audio to work now cant seem to get the connection I need.

I tried changing the peers, upload and downloads speed. when i changed the peers to 5 it seemed to work a little longer but in the end I still had to unplug the stick and plug back in.

any ideas??

Comment: Hi Danny, can you provide any relevant information that the "dmesg" commands gives you when using transmission. Can you also try another torrent client: http://askubuntu.com/questions/48546/list-of-gui-based-torrent-clients I say this part because with me, many times has transmission given me the same problem. I even have had to turn the router off for a while. But using another client helped. Test all of this and add it to your question.

Comment: Unpluged the stick? Are you using a mobile network connection?

Comment: Hi Luis so i ran "dmesg" I have a big report here- any speical part  you want to look at??? Let me try to clear up a few things. 1) I have a home router COMCAST not mobile connection- DOOGFAR 2) Internet works fine not downloading anything 3) start downloading anything even ubuntu updates internet connection drops.

Comment: ny-CM1745:~$ iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:"NETGEAR13"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.457 GHz  Access Point: 20:E5:2A:17:0F:5C   
          Bit Rate=130 Mb/s   Tx-Power:32 dBm   
          RTS thr:2347 B   Fragment thr:2346 B   
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:70/100  Signal level:-51 dBm  Noise level:-96 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

Comment: @Luis so im still getting the same problem I even went out to buy a different wireless card netgear N600 and still the same problem

Comment: @Danny hi danny, going out right now, when I get back i'll try to work on you case if nobody else solves this problem.

Comment: @ luis still having troubles with my internet connection