# Tremendously slow torrent speeds on Ubuntu 14.04 as compared to 12.04

Tags: server, bittorrent, deluge

I have a few seedboxes running Ubuntu 12.04 then I decided to try one on 14.04 and noticed that I could only slowly creep up to about 20mbps on the giga connection. I tried this with 2 different server providers and the results were the same. Only when the servers were running 12.04 that the speeds would hit the usual 80 - 100mbps.

Anyone else noticed this / know why this is happening on 14.04?

Comment: I had same issue with slow speed in torrent applictions. When I atached external usb wifi adapter problem disappeared. internal card is RTL8723AE on toshiba C870-17G laptop. External card is cheapest one from ebay with ATHEORS UB93 chip. Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: same here.. after updating from 12.04 to 14.04 torrent clients (deluge and transmission) are having sluggish speeds which jump all over the place. Not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: You can use alternative [deluge](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48546/list-of-gui-based-torrent-clients#48564)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using uTorrent that also may be why. I use Deluge and have the same internal card as the user above but noticed no difference.