# Torrent Software Download Help

Tags: bittorrent, torrent-client

I was wondering if someone could tell me what to do with a downloaded Torrent file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an application which is shipped by default in Ubuntu called `transmission`

You can open transmission by searching for it from the Dash(the top left Ubuntu logo). just click that logo and start writing `transmission`

[image]

So just open it locate the `.torrent` file and make some configuration like speed ,time ,etc... and `transmission` will take care of rest.

[image]

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48546/list-of-gui-based-torrent-clients) you can see a list of GUI based Torrent client

Comment: Thanks my first time but I have the Answer now.  Thanks

Comment: Please read this tour http://askubuntu.com/tour to learn how to use askubuntu