# Application BitTorrent Not Appearing After Installation

Tags: apt, package-management, bittorrent

Just tried installing BitTorrent via CLI, but the application isn't appearing in the Dash and doesn't seem to want to run from Terminal, either.

I used `sudo apt-cache search bittorrent` to verify it was in the package list, then `sudo apt-get install bittorrent`, `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, and finally `sudo apt-get autoremove` (just to be safe).

I checked Synaptic and sure enough, it has the little green square next to it. I'm at a bit of a loss, any clues on what gives? Could I be missing another package it needs to run or something along those lines? If so, how would I go about checking for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The executable is not actually named `bittorrent`:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ dpkg -L bittorrent | grep /bin
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/btlaunchmanycurses.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btlaunchmany.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btshowmetainfo.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btdownloadheadless.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btrename.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btdownloadcurses.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btreannounce.bittorrent
/usr/bin/bttrack.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btmakemetafile.bittorrent
/usr/bin/btcompletedir.bittorrent
andrew@corinth:~$
```

I see you are a Synaptic user so right click on the bittorrent green light and select Properties --> Installed Files and you will see the same in a gui:

[image]

The confusion is completely understandable though! If you are unsure of which particular executable to use perhaps try running something simple like:

```
btdownloadcurses http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent
```

This shows a very 'old school' torrenting window that is perhaps exactly what you are after:

[image]

Comment: Forgive me for making you spell it out (I'm still new and I've been up all night), but which one of those is the actual executable, then?

Comment: All of the files in `/usr/bin` are the actual executables :). What is your purpose in using bittorrent?

Comment: I ask mostly as bittorrent is an old client for torrent downloading and there are better clients around. If you are after typical usage an example is:  `btdownloadcurses http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/ubuntu-15.10-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent` but there are many options that can be added in.

Comment: Thanks for the further detail. Can you recommend any other clients? To be honest, I was only going with BitTorrent because I'm coming from Windows and it was the most familiar to me. I do, however find Transmission to be very easy to use (if perhaps a little basic).

Comment: I use rtorrent myself but there is a nice listing / review of available torrent clients here: http://askubuntu.com/q/48546/57576 which might help out. And welcome to Linux :)