# What is a good replacement for utorrent app?

Tags: utorrent, torrent-client, p2p

What are good p2p clients apps for Linux? I use **utorrent** on Windows 10 and I really like it, but I never tried any p2p clients on linux. Can you please recommend me a good one?

Thank You!

Comment: Try `vuze` its quite good

Comment: There is a reason transmission is the default app in Ubuntu.

Comment: Utorrent actually has a Linux port if you wish to continue using it, fairly simple to setup aswell. Here's a link to a post on how to install it (Still the same installation process). http://askubuntu.com/questions/530955/how-to-install-utorrent-v3-3-on-14-04

Comment: You might be interested in this AskUbuntu discussion: [List of GUI Based Torrent clients](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48546/list-of-gui-based-torrent-clients)

Comment: @Rinzwind.. I tried it and I find it nowhere near as good as utorrent in windows. it's very basic.  thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Qbittorrent
https://www.qbittorrent.org/
sudo apt-get install qbittorrent